# my apollo node js client not working for unknown reason

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have the following nodejs code :

```
    const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } = require('@apollo/client');

// Define the HTTP endpoint
const httpEndpoint = 'http://localhost:5000/graphql/';

// Create an HTTP link
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: httpEndpoint,
});

// Create an Apollo Client with the HTTP link
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

// Define your subscription query
const YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY = /* Your subscription query here */ `
  subscription OnAlertAdded {
    onAlertAdded(clientId: 1) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;


// Subscribe to the GraphQL subscription
client.subscribe({
  query: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
}).subscribe({
  next: (data) => {
    // Handle subscription data here
    console.log('Received data:', data);
  },
  error: (error) => {
    // Handle subscription errors here
    console.error('Subscription error:', error);
  },
});

// Handle any other logic or code here

// ...
```

it should connect to my graphql server which is working great with postman  .
it gives the following errors :

Uncaught Error Invariant Violation: An error occurred! For more details, see the full error text at https://go.apollo.dev/c/err#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.8.6%22%2C%22message%22%3A73%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D
at InvariantError (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules\ts-invariant\lib\invariant.cjs:16:28)
at invariant (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules\ts-invariant\lib\invariant.cjs:28:15)
at invariant (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\utilities\globals\globals.cjs:63:21)
at checkDocument (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs:386:13)
at DocumentTransform.transformDocument (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\utilities\utilities.cjs:501:9)
at QueryManager.transform (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\core\core.cjs:1647:39)
at QueryManager.startGraphQLSubscription (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\core\core.cjs:1834:22)
at ApolloClient.subscribe (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\node_modules@apollo\client\core\core.cjs:2381:34)
at  (c:\dev\GraphQL\appolo client node js\app.js:29:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at  (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
invariant.cjs:16
Process exited with code 1

any idea ?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion mentioned in the link provided as part of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink, gql } = require('@apollo/client');

const httpEndpoint = 'http://localhost:5000/graphql/';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: httpEndpoint,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY = gql`
  subscription OnAlertAdded {
    onAlertAdded(clientId: 1) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;


const handleSubscriptionError = (error) => {
  console.error('Subscription error:', error);
};


const subscribeToGraphQL = async () => {
  try {
    const subscription = await client.subscribe({
      query: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
    });

    subscription.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log('Received data:', data);
      },
      error: handleSubscriptionError,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleSubscriptionError(error);
  }
};
```